# Optional resources in Terraform 0.12 module

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I migrated terraform from 0.11 to 0.12. I have a module which should provision AWS SQS queue and optionally also dead-letter queue.

My repo is [here](https://github.com/piczmar/terraform-sqs-module)

I have the following condition on queue resource:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "regular_queue_with_dl" {
  count = var.attach_dead_letter_config ? 1 : 0

  redrive_policy = var.attach_dead_letter_config ? data.template_file.regular_queue_redrive_policy[count.index].rendered : null
...
}
```

On first run when `attach_dead_letter_config=true` the queue is created with DLQ, but when I want to remove DLQ (`attach_dead_letter_config=false`) the issue appears when terraform plan is running:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on modules/sqs/sqs.tf line 67, in resource "aws_sqs_queue" "regular_queue_with_dl":
  67:   redrive_policy             = var.attach_dead_letter_config ? data.template_file.regular_queue_redrive_policy[count.index].rendered : null
    |----------------
    | count.index is 0
    | data.template_file.regular_queue_redrive_policy is empty tuple
```

What is the proper way to create such optional resource in module?

Comment: Did this work ok in 0.11?  I was under the impression that the `? :` support should be better in 0.12, not worse...

Comment: For some reason your identical ternary is resolving to `true` for the `count` and false for the argument OR Terraform is hitting a bug here. However, your argument ternary is redundant with the `count` ternary. You only need the ternary for the `count` since an optional resource precludes an optional argument for the resource.

Answer (score 3):

Based on how the resource is named, it looks like this is an example of the Terraform 0.11 workaround of having two `resource` blocks with opposite `count` values, so that only one is created at a time in order to select between two different sets of arguments.

That workaround is no longer needed in Terraform 0.12 because you can just set `redrive_policy` to `null` in the situations where it isn't needed. You can also replace `template_file` with a call to [the `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) in Terraform 0.12, keeping everything self-contained:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "regular_queue" {
  redrive_policy = var.attach_dead_letter_config ? templatefile(
    "${path.module}/redrive_policy.tmpl", {
      # (...whatever you had in "vars" in the template_file data resource...)  
    },
  ) : null
...
}
```

Setting a resource argument to `null` is the same as omitting it entirely in Terraform 0.12.

Comment: Thanks ! This was helpful and solved my issue. I committed change [in github](https://github.com/piczmar/terraform-sqs-module/commit/7ad3018b6ba945e0b1d3a459cdc5dcc645959d49)

In fact I have still 2 resources for queue with and without DLQ because I don't want to create the DLQ always, only when `attach_dead_letter_config=true`.

Maybe you have an idea how to do it better?